# Juju wordpress charm doesn't update from git

Tags: juju, git, wordpress

I have set the `wp-config` string to my git repo. It gets everything fine but the charm is not picking up changes.

I make changes to my local copy of the `wp-content` then push it to my git remote repo expecting the charm to detect the changes and pull it but nothing happens.

Do I have to manually tell juju to check for a new revision?

Also is there any way to have juju pull a certain branch? This way I can have another juju charm for the development branch rather than separating the development to a different repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the charm isn't polling github for changes, it's simply pulling down the version on github on config-changed. So in order for it to pull down the new code you will need to trigger a change in this config field.

edit: You may want to file a bug for the charm requesting that a configuration field for git revision or-the-like be added.

Comment: Thanks removing the string and adding it again pulled the new version. It's not ideal but at least I can update it now. I still would like to know if there is a way to pull a certain branch though rather than the default branch.

Comment: Hello, maintainer of the charm here, please open a bug for this and I'll investigate a configuration option for branch as well as indicating a "sync_interval". https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/wordpress/+bugs

Comment: Thanks I will mark this as answered since it is a good workaround for now.